# How to initialize a structure variable to default values?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I am learning about structures now and I am trying to create default values for each variable of that structure type. My testing code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void){

    // DECLARING THE STRUCTURE
    struct str_client{
            char name[20] = "\0";
            int age = 0; 
            double money = 0.00; 
    };

    // DECLARING A VARIABLE OF THAT STRUCTURE TYPE (IN THIS CASE, AN ARRAY).
    str_client client[3];

return (0);}
```

Is this initialization the correct way to do it?

Comment: Arrays in C++ are indexed starting at zero.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This solves half of the problem (why the output was incorrect). I edited the question accordingly. Now the question lies specifically over the correct way to initialize variables of a structure.

Comment: `"\0"` is useless. Write `""`. The compiler adds `\0` of its own.

Comment: This is a perfectly good way to initialise a struct with default values.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use constructor.
Since class and struct are similar.

```
struct str_client{
        string name;
        int age; 
        double money; 
        str_client()
        {
            name = "";
            age = 0;
            money = 0.0;
        }
};
```

**Edit**
Using Member Initializer list will improve performance

```
struct str_client{
        string name;
        int age; 
        double money; 
        str_client()
            : name(""), age(0), money(0.0)
        {
        }
};
```

Comment: is this okay for you?

Comment: I am not  learning this part (class) yet! But it is good to know in advance another method. Thank you.

Comment: That’s a bad advice. Initialize members in the constructor only, if they depend on parameters passed to the constructor, or if their values are estimated at construction time. Further more use the initialized list of the constructor and the constructor body only if that is not possible. @user10906383

Comment: passing values while creating objects is also good idea.  str_client client = {"\0",0,0.0};

Comment: this can be achieved without constructors.

Comment: `str_client client = {"\0",0,0.0}` is not default initializing.

Comment: then use constructor